# Android MediaRecorder and setOutputFile

Tags: android, mediarecorder, file-io

I've read the Android SDK and I've found that the MediaRecorder class can take input from a Camera, Audio or other source and compress it. Through the setOutputFile method you can specify where you want the data to be stored (File or URI), but what if I want to store that data in a memory buffer and send it over a connection? Or process it before sending it? I mean is there a way not to create a file but to use a memory buffer only?

Answer (score 1):

You can of course read the file in later and do whatever you want with it in the way of processing.  Assuming that u holds the Uri to the resulting audio file, here is a code snippet that reads it into a byte array and then deletes the file.

```
String audioUri = u.getPath();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(u));
byte[] b = new byte[BUFSIZE];

BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(mFileName/*mFilePath*/)));
int byteCnt = 0;
while (0 <= (byteCnt = in.read(b, 0, BUFSIZE)))
   out.write(b, 0, byteCnt);
out.flush();
out.close();
// try to delete media file
try {
   // Delete media file pointed to by Uri
   new File(getRealPathFromURI(u)).delete();
} catch (Exception ex) {}


   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
      String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
      int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }
```