# Android hardware.camera and MediaRecorder

Tags: android, camera, video-capture, mediarecorder

How record two different quality(size) video from android device at the same time? One recorded video want to save sd card and another one is need in byte stream want to proccess some another things. How it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With the MediaRecorder you have no chance to get the Video as bytestream, you can only define a outputfile and da View to display the recording. But you can read in the outputfile simultaneously.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854163/android-mediarecorder-and-setoutputfile/6247373#6247373) for a Snipped

Comment: got byte from hardware.Camera class callback??is it true?

Comment: afaik this is true for pictures, but not for videos sorry